# Deploy WCF service in IIS error - "localhost is currently unable to handle this request"

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service.svc that I'm trying to deploy in IIS. I created an IIS application under the Default Web Site for the service using the .net 4.5 application pool, but when I try to browse the .svc file from within the IIS manager, the browser reports the following error "localhost is currently unable to handle this request".

If I click browse on the .svc file from within VS it resolves correctly to the WSDL metadata page and if I create an IIS application using the path in Visual Studio where the service folder resides it works and the url resolves. I don't understand why after I publish the service to another folder location that it doesn't work in IIS. Somehow it seems tied to Visual Studio installed location.

Can someone help me understand why this is? I need to be able to publish this service along w/ the associated bin files to another client system and have it work.

Web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
      </startup>
      <appSettings>
      </appSettings>

      <system.serviceModel>
        <client/>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttpBinding_testLink" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"/>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

        <!-- Service endpoints to expose/consume -->
        <services>
          <service name="testLink.testManager">

            <endpoint address="testService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_testLink" contract="testLink.ITestManager"/>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  />

          </service>
        </services>

        <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>

      </system.serviceModel>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: Can anyone help answer this?

Comment: post your service configuration (web.config) also do you see any errors logged in windows eventlog?

Comment: I posted it above. It's weird, I publish the service which creates the  service, web.Config and Bin folder. But when I create an application in IIS and point it to the published folder, the service doesn't resolve when I browse the service. But it works fine in VS when I browse the service file or if I create an ISS application and point it to the folder within VS it works there. Tnx for your help.

Comment: You have base address mentioned in your config file which is pointing to your IIS Express (Dev server). Remove base address configuration.

Comment: Pankaj, I removed the base addresses element and it still doesn't resolve. There must be something else that's missing when published and used apart Visual Studio.

Comment: @PankajKapare, base address is ignored when site is hosted in IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one could answer this problem, I dug deeper into it myself to solve it and found that when you publish your IIS WCF service as a published File System you need to place the published folder in the inetpub/wwwroot folder for the IIS manager to use otherwise it won't deploy and resolve correctly.

Comment: You are half right, inetput/wwroot is IIS's default website virtal path location. You can put your website/webapp anywhere, aslong as a virtual path is created that links to that location in IIS.